# Как ограничить поворот камеры в Unity 3D?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

У меня поворот камеры реализован через Rotate()

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Player;
    [SerializeField] public Joystick JoystickPlayer;

    public float TouchX;
    public float TouchY;
    public float Sensitivity = 200f;

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        TouchY = JoystickPlayer.Horizontal * Sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        TouchX = JoystickPlayer.Vertical * Sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        Player.Rotate(TouchY * new Vector3(0, 1, 0));

        transform.Rotate(-TouchX * new Vector3(1, 0, 0));
    }
}
```

Скрипт прикреплен к камере. Как можно ограничить поворот камеры по X?

Comment: Использовать [кватернионы](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Quaternion.html) (В самом низу пример того, как правильно использовать их) для поворота и ограничивать угол поворота с помощью [Mathf.Clamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html)

Comment: Камеру перемещать/вращать принято в LateUpdate(). Поэтому никаких "fixedDeltaTime" быть не должно. Во избежание багов в виде подергиваний камеры рекомендую код вращения камеры перенести из FixedUpdate() в LateUpdate() с использованием Time.deltaTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй `Mathf.Clamp(value, min, max)`
где `value` - твоё значение, `min` - минимальный угол поворота, `max` - максимальный)
Все значения `float`

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Да это костыль, для таких ограничений существует Mathf.Clamp

Comment: Да, и в правду, забыл о такой простой вещи))